# Upgrade reviewboard 2.x to 3.x

Tags: review-board

I am getting following error after upgraing reviewboard

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 0: invalid continuation byte



1- Restore DB to new host
2- Convert all tables from MYIsam to Innodb
```

Comment: My current review board version 2.5.x is hosted on RHEL6 and I want to upgrade it on version 3.0.15 and move it to RHEL7.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
We  need to copy the SECRET_KEY from the settings.py file on the old host into the one on the new server.